# Maximum call stack size exceeded error in javascript

Tags: javascript

HI guys i am getting error as Maximum call stack size exceeded from below code:

```
   function createDynamicSteps(part_count, start_point, end_point, current_display, num_dnum_type, isSoltion, stepCount, on_which_time, display_part_array)
{
    if(on_which_time == 'first_time')
    {
        for (var j = start_point; j < end_point; j++) 
        {
            display_part_array.push(current_display[j]);
        }
    }
    
    // Find the count of Operator and Variable
    var operator_count = _.where(display_part_array, {'Type':'operator'});
    var variable_count = _.where(display_part_array, {'Type':'variable'});
    var gen_str        = '';
    var arr_operator   = [];
    display_parts      = display_parts;
}
```

And i am getting error from this below line.

```
var operator_count = _.where(display_part_array, {'Type':'operator'});
```

Can any one help me where i did mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes get this if you accidentally import/embed the same JavaScript file twice. Check if you didn't do that for Underscore.js.

Comment: Checked..But it was included only once